# Can a C# class reference its own type as a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

#### Background

We're using the builder pattern in several places throughout the application. 
So far, we've written the following method in some of our builders, which has worked well.

```
public class MyBuilderClass
{
    private MyConcreteType entity;

    public MyBuilderClass() { this.entity = new MyConcreteType(); }

    public MyBuilderClass With<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expressionToFindProperty, TProperty valueToSet)
    {
     MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)expressionToFindProperty.Body;
                PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member.Member;
                property.SetValue(this.entity, valueToSet, null);
                return this;
    }
}
```

Allows us to do something along the lines of:

```
new MyBuilderClass().With(x=> x.MyProperty, "TheValue")
```

And and it infers that `MyProperty` in this case is a string.

### Goal

This is useful, so we'd like to be able to do it in an abstract fashion. Something along the lines of:

```
public abstract class AbstractBuilder<T, TBuilder> where TBuilder : AbstractBuilder<T, TBuilder>
{
    internal T entity;

    public TBuilder With<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expressionToFindProperty, TProperty valueToSet)
    {
        // Example usage: With(x => x.TrackingRecord, new TrackingRecord());
        MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)expressionToFindProperty.Body;
        PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member.Member;
        property.SetValue(this.entity, valueToSet, null);
        return (TBuilder)this;
    }

    public T Build()
    {
        return this.entity;
    }
}
```

So then our concrete builder would be along the lines of:

```
public class MyBuilderClass : AbstractBuilder<MyType, MyBuilderClass>
{
    // Code here
}
```

### Problem / Question

In the example above, we need to use `MyBuilderClass : AbstractBuilder<MyType, MyBuilderClass>`, referencing `MyBuilderClass` twice so that the `TBuilder` generic type of our abstract builder works out correctly.

Is there a change we could make to the `AbstractBuilder` in this case such that the syntax for our child classes could be shortened from:

```
public class MyBuilderClass : AbstractBuilder<PaymentRecord, MyBuilderClass>
```

to

```
public class MyBuilderClass : AbstractBuilder<PaymentRecord>
```

where `TBuilder` is inferred to be `MyBuilderClass`?

I'd love to get the syntactical sugar of not having to explicitly pass along the type of the builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, generics aren't fond of doing stuff like that. You'll need to pass the type argument.

Total side note; if you are frequently building objects like that the reflection could get quite expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I figured it'd be unlikely but wanted a sanity check to be sure. Agree on the expensiveness; in this case the builders are being used strictly for some integration test work and the perf hit is negligible; we're tracking it.

Answer (score 0):

A potential is to have the `with` function return `AbstractBuilder<TType>`

For example:

```
public abstract class AbstractBuilder<T>
{
    internal T entity;

    public AbstractBuilder<T> With<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expressionToFindProperty, TProperty valueToSet)
    {
        // Example usage: With(x => x.TrackingRecord, new TrackingRecord());
        MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)expressionToFindProperty.Body;
        PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)member.Member;
        property.SetValue(this.entity, valueToSet, null);
        return this;
    }

    public T Build()
    {
        return this.entity;
    }
}
```

Then you can do the simple extension desired:

```
public class MyBuilderClass : AbstractBuilder<PaymentRecord>
```

And call it like so:

```
var builder = new MyBuilderClass();
var record = builder
            .With(f => f.TrackingRecord, new MyTrackingRecord())
            .Build();
```

The downside is that it limits your fluent api to the abstract class after a call to `with`, unless you override the function call to return the specific builder type.